# Add labels to timeline map created using leaftime plug-in for leaflet in R

Tags: javascript, r, leaflet

Below is example code taken from the examples given in the documentation for the R leaftime package. It creates a map with a timeline that shows the points appearing over time. I would like labels to be added to the points to show the id number of each point. By looking at the code, I assume the JS function in the code is actually passing JavaScript to leaflet to customise the map. I understand from here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245621/how-to-label-geojson-points-in-leaflet that I need to add in the tooltip function but have been unable to modify the below R code to achieve the desired result. I would be grateful for any assistance.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaftime)
library(htmltools)

#Build data.frame
power <- data.frame(
"Latitude" = c(
  33.515556, 38.060556, 47.903056, 49.71, 49.041667, 31.934167,
  54.140586, 54.140586, 48.494444, 48.494444
),
"Longitude" = c(
  129.837222, -77.789444, 7.563056, 8.415278, 9.175, -82.343889,
  13.664422, 13.664422, 17.681944, 17.681944
),
"start" = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10),
"end" = as.Date("2015-01-10")
)
power$id<-seq.int(nrow(power))

# use geojsonio to convert data.frame
power_geo <- geojsonio::geojson_json(power,lat="Latitude",lon="Longitude")

leaflet(power_geo) %>%
addTiles() %>%
setView(44.0665,23.74667,2) %>%
addTimeline(
  timelineOpts = timelineOptions(
    pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "
      function(data, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 10,
      color: 'black',
      fillColor: 'pink',
      fillOpacity: 1
      })
      }
      "
    )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer from Falke Design, here is the full code to add `id` to the label.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaftime)
library(htmltools)

#Build data.frame
power <- data.frame(
"Latitude" = c(
  33.515556, 38.060556, 47.903056, 49.71, 49.041667, 31.934167,
  54.140586, 54.140586, 48.494444, 48.494444
),
"Longitude" = c(
  129.837222, -77.789444, 7.563056, 8.415278, 9.175, -82.343889,
  13.664422, 13.664422, 17.681944, 17.681944
),
"start" = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 10),
"end" = as.Date("2015-01-10")
)
power$id<-seq.int(nrow(power))

# use geojsonio to convert data.frame
power_geo <- geojsonio::geojson_json(power,lat="Latitude",lon="Longitude")

leaflet(power_geo) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(44.0665,23.74667,2) %>%
  addTimeline(
    timelineOpts = timelineOptions(
      pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "
        function(data, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            radius: 10,
            color: 'black',
            fillColor: 'pink',
            fillOpacity: 1
          }).bindTooltip(
            // data.properties will have the columns from sf in R
            'id: ' + data.properties.id + '<br/>start: ' + data.properties.start,
            {permanent: true}
          ).openTooltip()
        }
        "
      )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pointToLayer = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "
      function(data, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: 10,
      color: 'black',
      fillColor: 'pink',
      fillOpacity: 1
      }).bindTooltip('I am a circle.',{permanent: true}).openTooltip();
      }
      "
    )
```

Here a example with normal JS:
https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/yqfs1bnk/

Comment: That works and adds the 'I'm a circle' text but now I need to find out how to put in the id values in there rather than just having the same text for each one.

Comment: you have the `data` object, create a output `console.log(data);` and then get the id from there